# Using of system colors in WinUI3 without DynamicResource - is it possible?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2019, desktop-application, winui-3

I am porting some XAML from WPF to WinUI3. As far as I understand for now I can't use DynamicResource in WinUI3, but is there any workaround to use system color like this one in WPF:

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the corresponding [theme resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-theme-resources?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077):

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorHighlightColor}"/>
```